# Debug jQuery form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form that submits to a url using the action attribute `<form action='/example/url'>`. It uses the jQuery validation plugin.

```
jQuery("form#page-0").validate({
        ignore: ':hidden'
        ,rules: {"product_id_page-0":{"required":true},"name_f":{"required":true,"regex":["^[^=:<>{}()\"]+$",""]},"name_l":{"required":true,"regex":["^[^=:<>{}()\"]+$",""]},"email":{"required":true,"remote":{"url":"\/premium\/ajax?do=check_uniq_email&_url=L3ByZW1pdW0vbG9naW4\/YW1lbWJlcl9yZWRpcmVjdF91cmw9JTJGcHJlbWl1bSUyRnNpZ251cC5waHA="}},"login":{"required":true,"rangelength":["6","32"],"regex":["^([0-9a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_ ]+[0-9a-zA-Z_]|[0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$",""],"remote":{"url":"\/premium\/ajax?do=check_uniq_login"}},"pass":{"required":true,"rangelength":["6","32"]},"_pass":{"required":true}}
        ,messages: {"product_id_page-0":{"required":"Please choose a membership type"},"name_f":{"required":"Please enter your First Name","regex":"Please enter your First Name"},"name_l":{"required":"Please enter your Last Name","regex":"Please enter your Last Name"},"email":{"required":"Please enter valid Email","remote":"--wrong email--"},"login":{"required":"Please enter valid Username. It must contain at least 6 characters","rangelength":"Please enter valid Username. It must contain at least 6 characters","regex":"Username contains invalid characters - please use digits, letters or spaces","remote":"--wrong login--"},"pass":{"required":"Please enter Password","rangelength":"Password must contain at least 6 letters or digits"},"_pass":{"required":"This field is required"}}
        //,debug : true
        ,errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent());
        }
        ,submitHandler: function(form, event){form.submit();}
        // custom validate js code start

        ,errorElement: "span"
        // custom validate js code end
    });
```

The problem is that sometimes the form submits to the url before the validator fires. I'm suspicious of `submitHandler: function(form, event){form.submit();}` because I don't understand what the `event` parameter is doing. In the documentation for [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) there's no mention of a second parameter.

Any suggestions for debugging the form are also welcome. Variables to log or other ways to view what's happening. I did set `debug:true` but it doesn't seem to spit any errors to the console.

Comment: If the docs for `submitHandler` don't mention the `event` argument, so why then are you using it?  The docs are correct, there is no second argument.

Comment: @Sparky actually there is a second argument `event` but not documented (I don't know why), it was introduced by this pull request [`#233`](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/pull/233) in 2011.

Comment: @Arkni, odd it's not documented.  Even stranger it was merged for an edge case.  Regardless, it's not needed in the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that sometimes the form submits to the url before the validator fires.

It might be because you've specified a non-existant rule.   There is no such rule/method called `regex`.  However, there is one called `pattern` contained within the `additional-methods.js` file.  This is the root cause of your problems.  Once the `required` rule is satisfied, the plugin attempts to evaluate the `regex` rule and chokes.

> I'm suspicious of `submitHandler: function(form, event){form.submit();}` because I don't understand what the `event` parameter is doing. In the documentation for jquery validation there's no mention of a second parameter.

If you don't understand what it's doing and it's not in the docs, then why did you put the `event` argument into your code?

The documentation is correct, there is no second argument.  However, having the additional arguments is merely superfluous and will not break anything.

---

You employ a very unusual code formatting style that makes it difficult to read and troubleshoot.

```
,submitHandler: function(form, event){form.submit();}
```

1. There is no second argument for this callback, so you can remove `event`.
2. Since you only have `form.submit()` within your `submitHandler`, it's not doing anything different from the default.  In other words, remove the entire `submitHandler`, and after validation the form will submit to the `action` attribute as per the default.

---

**NOTES**:

1. `ignore: ":hidden"` is the default behavior, so you don't need to specify it.
2. It's not necessary to enclose the rule names within quotes.

---

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/1e82p64f/**

Comment: I didn't write the code, I'm just stuck fixing it. Thanks though.

Comment: @icicleking, my demo shows a version that is working.  The main issue causing your problem is the non-existant `regex` rule.

Comment: thanks, again. Unfortunately, removing the regex methd removed some of the validation functionality, from the validation docs, "For simple one-off validation, you can use the bundled pattern method (in additional methods, source in src/additional/pattern.js) to validate a field against a regular expression. In general, it is a good idea to encapsulate those regular expressions inside their own method. If you need lots of slightly different expressions, try to extract a common parameter." I'm going to follow your example and better layout the code to see if I can refactor

Comment: @icicleking, yes, as you quoted from the docs, it's called the **`"pattern"`** method, not the `"regex"` method as you had used.